# How is the function calPoints returning null value?

Tags: c, stack

In order to identify the problem in the code, I tried to print the value of top after for loop and within each condition in the for loop. The value of top however cannot be printed after for loop where as it is printed after each iteration of for loop.Added to that the the values of stack are not getting printed either after for loop.

```css
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define max 1000 
void push(int *stack, int top, int n) {
  if(top==max-1) {
    return;
  }
  else {
    stack[top]=n;
  }
}

void pop(int *stack, int top) {
  if(top==-1) {
    return;
  }
}

int calPoints(char **ops, int opsSize) {
  int st[max],
  sum,
  p,
  x,
  i;
  int top=-1;
  for(i=0;
  i<opsSize;
  ++i) {
    if(strcmp(ops[i], "+")==0) {
      int sum=st[top]+st[top-1];
      ++top;
      push(st, top, sum);
      printf("sum= %d %d\n", sum, top);
    }
    else if(strcmp(ops[i], "D")==0) {
      int p=st[top]*2;
      top++;
      push(st, top, p);
      printf("p= %d %d\n", p, top);
    }
    else if(strcmp(ops[i], "C")==0) {
      pop(st, top);
      --top;
    }
    else {
      int x=atoi(ops[i]);
      ++top;
      push(st, top, x);
      printf("x=%d %d\n", x, top);
    }
  }
  printf("%d", top);
  int s=0;
  for(i=0;
  i<=top;
  ++i) {
    s+=st[i];
    printf("%d\t",st[i]);
  }
  return s;
}

int main() {
  char *c[5]= {
    "5",
    "2",
    "C",
    "D",
    "+"
  }
  ;
  int x=6;
  calPoints(c, x);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have a buffer overflow in `calPoints`. https://godbolt.org/z/hKaTEnrz6

Comment: You have an array of 5 pointers to strings but tell your function, the length is 6. That will cause an out of bounds access in your `for`loop.

Comment: Where did you get that stack implementation. I've seen similar thing a few days ago in another question. That's terrible. Leaving the task to update stack pointer (`top`) to caller of the stack is an invitation for errors. Go look for some stack examples where you use some struct handling all the required state variables and where the `push`/`pop` or other helper functions do the updates to stack pointer internally. Besides that, your `pop` doesn't even do anything.

Comment: You should also adopt some common formatting rules. Writing all those variable definitions below each other is weird. That is normally done if you provide the type in each line. Also writing the fields of `for` loop header looks strange. That reduces readability a lot.

Comment: Please also add what output you expect and what you get.

Comment: The reason that 99.9% of the examples of `for( )` loops are written the way they are is because that is the style that has worked for millions of coders. Departing from _expected_ conventions requires a much stronger reason than, "I like it that way." I'd waste no time firing an employee for that sort of code. (In fact, I didn't waste any time.)

Comment: ... What's the qn, again? 